# How to accept format='%I:%M %p' in a django model Form?

Tags: python, django-forms

I am having problems to get validated a django form, Here is my django form:

```
class reservaForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Reservas
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
        'guests': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'id':'id_invitados','min':'0','class':'form-control form-control-solid'}),
        'date': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'date','class':'form-control form-control-solid flatpickr-input'}),
        'timestarts': forms.TimeInput(format='%I:%M %p',attrs={'id':'id_time_starts','type':'time','class':'form-control form-control-solid','readonly':'readonly','onchange':'ajustarHora()'}),
        'timeends': forms.TimeInput(format='%I:%M %p',attrs={'id':'id_time_ends','type':'time','class':'form-control form-control-solid','readonly':'readonly'}),
    }
```

I am a javascript calendar function which makes a fancy user interfase, however when submitting the form I get the following error:

> hora_inicio
>
> Enter a
> valid time.

The value the form is submitting is '5:30 PM', but is not getting as a valid format/value.

Any suggestion on how to make this be accepted by the form?